# How to overwrite a branch in Git with master

Tags: git

I have an old dev branch that is completely outdated. I don't want to remove it but I do want to replace its contents entirely with the master branch.
Meaning, I want dev_branch = master

I tried:

```
git merge -s ours dev_branch
```

Didn't work though...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you want all changes from `master` in `dev_branch`, then:

```
git checkout dev_branch
git reset --hard master
```

This only works if other people haven't cloned the repository.

If you have `dev_branch` pushed to a remote already, you have to do:

```
git push --force
```

To force-push to the remote. Warning: This will break the history of the branch for people who cloned it before! Then, other people will have to do a `git pull --rebase` on the `dev_branch` to get the changes.

---

You can also rename the dev branch to something old and then make a new branch from `master` with the same name:

```
git branch -m dev_branch old_dev_branch
git branch -m master dev_branch
```

---

Or, use the `ours` strategy — not sure why it wouldn't work for you:

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours dev_branch
git checkout dev_branch
git merge master
```

Comment: With the renaming solution, I think you will find that you now can't push `dev_branch` to origin (if it had one), and you will also no longer have a `master` branch locally.

Comment: Thanks @slhck! For some reason, my stage branch was not being updated after doing a normal merge. It kept on saying that my stage branch was up-to-date. Using the "ours" strategy solved this for me.

Comment: ours would only affect conflicted chunks, but he wants to completely renew the branch, not only the conflicts !? (this is at least what I need to do and why I found this Q) - I will go for the rename!

Answer (score 1):

Why do that? You can delete the branch if it isn't needed anymore (But why? Branches cost next to nothing.). Or you can rename it:

```
git branch -m dev_branch obsolete_dev
```

Or you could do this to delete it:

```
git branch -D dev_branch
```

Now create a new branch off `master` (assuming you are on it):

git branch dev_branch

See `git branch --help` for further options (setting up remotes and all that jazz).

If you now have new branches, you'll have to synchronize with any peer repositories.

Best way to avoid hassle: Have an "active" development branch, if it goes stale, abandon it and create a new one. No history lost that way (could prove crucial sometime).

Have e.g. a branch for each major version, develop on branches off those to fix version bugs, master forges ahead. Use cherry-pick and perhaps merges to port fixes to older versions.

Comment: Q: > Why do that? You can delete the branch if it isn't needed anymore 


A:  A possible reason for why one might not want to delete the branch is that CI tooling might deploy the dev server or a testing server based on that branch, and removing that branch might remove the server, or break it.